# MacBook Pro 2017 has problems when live booting from usb into parrot linux distro

Tags: disk-utility, usb, startup, unix, bootable-disk

I used Balena Etcher software to flash my usb with the image / iso of parrot linux distro the security edition. the live booting went fine but when it was all booted up I could not move mouse or do anything! can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: MacBook Pro's do not have mice. So, what kind of mouse is this?

Comment: Ohh sorry, wrote my question in a hurry I meant track pad